# Google maps/street view negative coordinates

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-street-view

I am using 2 node modules which are google-map-react and react-google-streetview. I made some testing using my home coordinates (which are both positives) and it's working just fine. However, when I start having a coordinate that is negative, street view display me a big black screen, and google maps consider this negative value as NaN...
I have found nothing about that, did this happened to anyone else?

Comment: show your code  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it appeared the module I was trying to use was full of bug despite being frequently downloaded and updated not so long ago.

So instead, I used @react-google-maps/api and it works mighty fine (use the 1.9.5, as by when I write this, the 2.0.0 is still in alpha and unstable (it couldn't render myself a map)).